# Evolution of multicellular eggs

Tags: evolution, eggs

Which animals where the first in which ova were not simply released, but instead provided with some additional nutrition and/or protection in the form of a larger egg?

Comment: What animals are you talking about? Unless I am mistaken, eggs are, by definition, single cells.

Comment: @kmm the term 'egg' is also used for the vessel surrounding the ovum. I don't know if there is any other term for what we commonly call the egg (for example a chicken egg).